# SSLSocketFactory finding the time spent on road on java

Tags: java, sockets, jsse

I am making a client/sever connection by using SSL Sockets of java. I am sending a long string to the server from client and then I am recording that string to a text file on server part. Which is really basic.

What I want to do is I want to learn the time it takes to transfer that string to my server from my client. How can I achieve this result? Are there anyone that can give me an advise? If you need to see my code this code uses the same structure with my code: [click](http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Take the time when it starts and the time when it stops and calculate the difference.